# How to add an existing view to a UIScrollView

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview

I have created a view and the content is larger than the screen.  How do I add this view as a subview of a scrollview?  For some reason I can't do this in Document Outline.  It will only let me add the scrollview as a subview of the existing view.

Answer (score 1):

Select your view in Interfacebuilder and then use the menu command Editor:Embed In:Scroll View

[image]
[image]

Comment: Embed in does appear in the menu, but it is greyed out so I can't select it. I'm using stack views and auto layout, but have no idea if this is relevant.

Comment: Xcode is very picky about selecting the right embed source. You should try to select your scroll view in the left sidebar of the storyboard editor to make sure you have selected nothing else and then go for the menu command. Embedding UISackViews in scroll views is extremely common and always works. Auto Layout is not an issue.

Comment: I think I have this figured... You can't embed the top view, or superview? in a scrollview.  It can only be embedded in a Navigation Controller or Tab Bar Controller.  I need to select all subviews and embed that.  The scrollview will be a child view of the top view.  I'll give this a go.

Comment: Glad I could help. And yes - the very top view cannot be embedded in other views - which makes sense once you think about it. And moving forward - no - you don't have to necessarily select all subviews and embed them. You can pick and choose. Like in the picture on the right I provided, you could select the view named transport and embed it further.